# Baselines comparison for Cox regression & Kaplan-Meier

Tags: cox-model, kaplan-meier

If I am not mistaken baselines for Cox regression & Kaplan-Meier are equal

```
library("survival")
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data =  lung)
quantile(survfit(res.cox), conf.int = F)
25  50  75 
170 310 550 

km = survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung)
quantile(km, conf.int = F)
25  50  75 
170 310 550 

quantile(survfit(res.cox), conf.int = F) = quantile(km, conf.int = F)
```

That's ok. But in my own dataset I get

```
w = coxph(Surv(stag, event) ~ 1, data = df) 
> quantile(survfit(w), conf.int = F)
       25        50        75 
 19.94251  50.72690 106.84189 
km = survfit(Surv(stag,event) ~ 1, data = df)
quantile(km, conf.int = F)
 25       50       75 
 19.8768  50.7269 106.8419
```

The values are almost equal but there is a difference! Why is this happening, what are the differences in the calculations baselines for Cox regression & Kaplan-Meier?

Answer (score 1):

The difference might come from the handling of tied survival times in the two approaches. The [Kaplan-Meier estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator) simply uses the number of events at each event time in its calculations. To accommodate the multiple covariates that need to be evaluated in general in a Cox model, there needs to be special handling of multiple events occurring at the same time. There are 3 options for handling ties in `coxph()`.

So my guess is that you had some early time point with more than 1 event, leading to the *very* slight discrepancy (less than 1%) for the 25th percentile time. The 50th and 75th percentile times are identical except for rounding.